# Delay in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, time, delay, wait

i'm running a script that is constantly putting out an array of values called `rects[0]`. Here is the code:

```
function draw_faces(ctx, rects, sc, max) {
            var on = rects.length;
            if(on && max) {
                jsfeat.math.qsort(rects, 0, on-1, function(a,b){return (b.confidence<a.confidence);})
            }
            var n = max || on;
            n = Math.min(n, on);
            var r;
            for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                r = rects[i];
                ctx.strokeRect((r.x*sc)|0,(r.y*sc)|0,(r.width*sc)|0,(r.height*sc)|0);
                if (rects[0].width > 41.5  && rects[0].height > 41.5)
                                        WAIT TIME AND CHECK AGAIN
                     THEN console.log("face length");

            }
        }
```

What I want to do is after the initial if statement checking the rects[0] value, I want to wait some time, then check again if those variables are still above the threshold of 41.5 then some action, in this case console.log("face length").

So essentially I need to check `rects[0]` and then wait for a few seconds then check again if its value is above the threshold.

Comment: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)?

Comment: `setTimeout(func, i*delay)`

Comment: but that inside the loop executes the function multiple times right? I just want to execute it once.

Comment: I need this to finish synchronously, wait for the timeout to be done before doing anything else.

Comment: @user2266621, rethink your requirements.  JS with delays will never be synchronous.  Especially if you want a few second delay in there, you wouldn't want to halt everything waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a delay, you want to set some code to run after a few seconds.  Use `setTimeout` like this:

```
function draw_faces(ctx, rects, sc, max) {
        var on = rects.length;
        if(on && max) {
            jsfeat.math.qsort(rects, 0, on-1, function(a,b){return (b.confidence<a.confidence);})
        }
        var n = max || on;
        n = Math.min(n, on);
        var r;
        for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            r = rects[i];
            ctx.strokeRect((r.x*sc)|0,(r.y*sc)|0,(r.width*sc)|0,(r.height*sc)|0);
            if (rects[0].width > 41.5  && rects[0].height > 41.5) {

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        if (rects[0].width > 41.5  && rects[0].height > 41.5) {
                            console.log("face length");
                        }
                    }, 3000);
            }
        }
    }
```